# R exporting plots through a for cycle

Tags: r, export, jpeg

I have a problem exporting some statistical plot on R.
I am using the function jpeg() with the function dev.off()...I have replicated the code and it gives me the same error:

```
data1<-rnorm(n = 1000,mean = 0,sd = 1)
data<-cbind(data,data,data,data)

for(i in c(1,2,3)){
  print(i)
  if(i ==1){
    #Histograms and density
    jpeg(paste(getwd(),'/Hist_',i,'.jpg',sep=''))
    histogram( data[,1],xlab = "data" )
    dev.off()
    #boxplot
    jpeg(paste(getwd(),'/Boxplot_',i,'.jpg',sep=''))
    boxplot(data[,1],xlab='cluster', ylab='data')
    dev.off()
  }else{
    #Histograms and density
    jpeg(paste(getwd(),'/Hist_',i,'.jpg',sep=''))
    histogram( data[,1],xlab = "data" )
    dev.off()
    #boxplot
    jpeg(paste(getwd(),'/Boxplot_',i,'.jpg',sep=''))
    boxplot(data[,1],xlab='cluster', ylab='data')
    dev.off()
  }
}
```

if I set i=1 and then I run the relative cycle I have no problems, but if I run the entire cycle R exports only the boxplot images....does anyone know why?
thank you !

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. It's much easier to help if we can copy/paste the code into R to test it. It's possible your approximations have removed the actual problem.

Comment: I have replicated the problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only problem in your code is `data<-cbind(data,data,data,data)` where it show be `data<-cbind(data1,data1,data1,data1)` and the fact that histogram is not base-r function. If you fix above, and set `histogram=hist`, everything works fine.

Comment: Or if you really want to use `histogram()` rather than `hist()`, use `print(histogram( data[,1],xlab = "data" ))` to make it draw.

Comment: It works! This example is simplified, I need to create an histogram of data for each level of another variable (cluster), so I think the function histogram() is better...print() makes it work! Thank you!